# Count data from subdocuments in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am trying to count data with nested subdocuments and I am not able to understand how I could get what I want (and if it is possible).

I have the following mongoose schema which is used for a list of appointments:

```js
var AppointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 {
  clinic: {
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
   ref: 'Clinic',
   required: true,
  },
  type: {
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
   ref: 'AppointmentType',
   required: true,
  }
 }
);

var ClinicSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 {
  name: {
   type: String,
   maxlength: 25,
   required: true,
  }
 }
);

var AppointmentTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 {
  name: {
   type: String,
   minlength: 2,
   maxlength: 25,
   required: true,
  }
 }
);
```

From that list of appointments, I am looking to report metrics to know the number of different type of appointments per clinic.

So far I am only able to get a count per type of appointments regardless the clinic using the following aggregation:

```js
db.appointments.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$type',  //$type is the column name in collection
                count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: { count: -1 }
        }
    ]
);
```

This is returning me the following results:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5838ef21b19aee730b8ae6c8"), "count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5838efa4d695cb7839672417"), "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5838efb4d695cb7839672419"), "count" : 3
```

But what I'd like to get would be as follows:

```js
{
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Name of the clinic #1",
  count: [
   {
    id: 10,
    name: "Appointment Type #10",
    count: 4,
   },
   {
    id: 20,
    name: "Appointment Type #20",
    count: 1,
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "Name of the clinic #2",
  count: [
   {
    id: 10,
    name: "Appointment Type #10",
    count: 5,
   },
   {
    id: 20,
    name: "Appointment Type #20",
    count: 2,
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following aggregation query will give you a similar result:

```
db.appointments.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$clinic",
                count: { $push: "$type" }
            }

        },
        {
            $project:{
                _id: 0,
                id: "$_id._id",
                name: "$_id.name",
                "count": 1
            }
        }
    ]
).pretty();
```

Example output:

```
{
        "count" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("583ecd06401ce04a0ca7e170"),
                        "name" : "Appointment Type 1"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("583ecd09401ce04a0ca7e171"),
                        "name" : "Appointment Type 2"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("583ecd0c401ce04a0ca7e172"),
                        "name" : "Appointment Type 3"
                }
        ],
        "id" : ObjectId("583eccf6401ce04a0ca7e16d"),
        "name" : "Clinic 1"
}
{
        "count" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("583ecd06401ce04a0ca7e170"),
                        "name" : "Appointment Type 1"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("583ecd0c401ce04a0ca7e172"),
                        "name" : "Appointment Type 3"
                }
        ],
        "id" : ObjectId("583eccfd401ce04a0ca7e16e"),
        "name" : "Clinic 2"
}
{
        "count" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("583ecd06401ce04a0ca7e170"),
                        "name" : "Appointment Type 1"
                }
        ],
        "id" : ObjectId("583ecd01401ce04a0ca7e16f"),
        "name" : "Clinic 3"
}
```

What does your `count: 4` within `count` relate to?